# With Oracle JDBC driver seeing extra connection doing SELECT SYS_CONTEXT Query

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle12c

Unable to find Oracle documents referring to the cause for this Query from Connection. Using the JDBC Driver ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar

We saw that there was one connection for brief time running
SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'CURRENT_SCHEMA') FROM DUAL

In Code

```
connection = provider.getConnection();
connection.setNetworkTimeout(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(), network_timeout);
```

Comment: Drivers pretty commonly run small data dictionary queries-- is this query causing you a problem?  This is likely the sort of implementation detail that no one is going to be able to answer without looking at the driver's code.

Comment: No problem as such, just that I need to be confirmed that this is Driver and reason for it if there are supportive documentation/source code reference for the same. Thanks.

Comment: You could run the JDBC driver through a decompiler and try to find the query.  Realistically, no driver is going to document every query that a driver might execute particularly when those queries can and do change between versions.  What is the DBA's concern with this query?

Comment: DBA wanted to know the origin of it and in what instances it gets executed.

Comment: Why does the DBA want to know?  Databases have thousands of queries.  No DBA has time to look at every query let alone chase down where the query is coming from and what causes it to be executed.  It would only make sense to do so if the query was causing some sort of issue or appearing on some sort of "Top N" report.  Hence the original question-- is this query causing some sort of problem?

Comment: Like said No Problem, it was DBA who was asking for.

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle JDBC Driver opens max(n+1) connections if n connections are defined as maximum number of connections in connection pool. The 1 is a administrative session handling the pool.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, here there is no pool, just plain DriverManager.getConnection with jdbcurl. Still does it holds good for n+1 connections? Also is this Query in question run by JDBC Driver - Any Oracle document you could point to if you have, I need to prove this to my DBA :)

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle JDBC Driver opens max(n+1) connections if n connections are defined as maximum number of connections in connection pool. The 1 is a administrative session handling the pool.
This is not a JDBC only behaviour but seen in Oracle  .NET provider and OCI, too - as far I can remember